# Google Analytics funnel step not working correctly

Tags: google-analytics

I am running into a strange issue with the goal funnel that I set up for my Shopify store.

I used the following URL for step 3, which corresponds to the customer choosing whether they'll use a guest checkout or if they'll create a new account:

/account/login/*

I used the wildcard because Shopify appends that URL with a unique ID.

Problem is, when I look at the Funnel Visualization report, I am seeing a lot of exits from step 2 (view cart), and the exit URLs are all of the type "/account/login/0f53d3781dcdf4feie6a3", which actually means they didn't actually drop from the funnel, they went to step 3, and should have been captured.

Any idea why this is happening? Did I just set things up incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!

Lukas

Answer (score 1):

- Google Analytics does not use wildcards, it uses regular expressions (not all regexp features are supported, though).
- if you want to you regular expressions in your funnel steps the
  matchtype for the destination url needs to be set to regular
  expression, too.
- The star character (asterisk) means "match any number of the preceding character". So "/account/login/*" would match e.g. "/account/login//" or "/account/login/////" but not "/account/login/0f53d3781dcdf4feie6a3"
- You should be okay if you use the "any" character which is "." (dot), so your regexp for the funnel step would like this:

  /account/login/.*

(match anything that includes the phrase "/account/login/" and has an abritrary number of abritrary characters after that). Or you might try to craft a regexp that matches only valid session ids (personally I would not bother).

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue due to problem in Regex. Due to improper Regex, pages which should have been counted in Step 3 are appearing as exit pages in Step 2. Let me explain in detail.

The Regex you have applied is-"/account/login/*". Here * at the end means it Match zero or more of the previous items. Means it will track URLs like "/account/login//","/account/login",
and "/account/login///". But in your case URLs are different as it is being appended by Unique ID.So existing Regex will not track what you are intending to.

To solve your problem i'd recommend you to use this Regex- /account/login/.* 
I believe that this should work as a dot,means get any character and a star means repeat the last character zero or more times.This means that the dot could match any letter in the alphabet, any digit, any number. And the star right after it matches the ability of the dot to match any single character, and keep on going. So this Regex will match all the URLs you are intending to track, even with random Unique IDs.

Hope i have answered your query.

Do let me know if this works for you.